# pandas compute difference using to column filters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like:

```
| country | year | people 
| US      | 1990 | 20 
| US      | 1991 | 34 
| ..      | ..   | ..
| US      | 2020 | 456 
| UK      | 1990 | 5 
| UK      | 1991 | 7 
| ..      | ..   | ..
| UK      | 2020 | 300
```

I would like to compute the difference between 2020 and 1990 for each of the countries, expected output:

```
|country | difference 
|US      | 436
|UK      | 295
```

Comment: edited, wrong typing.

Answer (score 1):

Since the years of interest are 2020 and 1990, we filter for just those years, sort the people column in descending order, groupby country, and use [numpy subtract](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html) and [numpy reduce](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) to get the difference:

```
(df.query('year==[2020,1990]')
 .sort_values('people',ascending=False)
 .groupby('country',sort=False)
 .agg(difference=('people',np.subtract.reduce))
 )

          difference
country 
   US       436
   UK       295
```

Note that the groupby is not sorted - this ensures the sorted values are not tampered with(we need each column to have the highest at the top, so that the subtractions and reduction method in the aggregation will yield positive values)

For division :

```
(df.query('year==[2020,1990]')
 .sort_values('people',ascending=False)
 .groupby('country',sort=False)
 .agg(fst=('people','first'), lst=('people','last'))
 .assign(division=lambda x: x.fst.div(x.lst))
 )
```

Comment: what will be the numpy command if I want to divide instead of the difference meaning `value2020/value1990`? what function should I use to replace `np.subtract.reduce`

Comment: added detail to the code. I am not sure you can use numpy divide, in grouping